High current flowing through NOT gate latch
This is a follow-up to my previous question. This is the circuit I ended up with:

When I build this circuit on a breadboard using a CD74HC04E DIP14 IC (datasheet), everything works fine. If I keep the button pressed for too long, then sometimes the latch will stay on and I need to press the button again to stop it, and that's fine and I guess to be expected.
But when I use instead a much tinier SN74LVC2G04DBVR SOT23 IC (datasheet), the circuit still performs fine, but now when the button is held for too long (and really too long here just means half a second), then not only does the circuit become impossible to turn off no matter how many times the button is pressed again, but current starts flowing through the IC itself.
Normally the IC only uses up a few uA of current, but in this scenario, over 40mA flow through it (digital multimeter in current mode connected between the power supply and VCC pin of the IC), which is obviously orders of magnitude more than expected.
I believe I may be experiencing some sort of CMOS latch-up, but I am at a loss on how to mitigate it (other than simply not pressing the button for too long, but that's not really a solution).

Connect an oscilloscope at some output. Maybe there are high-frequency oscillations. Also, experiment with various C1 values.

Do you have the supply bypassed with a capacitor right at the IC power pins? If not try putting something like a 100nF cap there.

If that is your schematics, you are not revealing the supply voltage, or if there are any bypass caps. And those are not the only things that are needed for the circuit to operate right. If you can answer those questions, I'll try to formulate an answer.

@Justme The VCC pin of the double NOT gate is connected to the same 3V supply that the anode of the LED is. The GND pin goes to ground. There is no other component other than what's in the diagram.

@GodJihyo No I don't, but I can for sure try!

@Circuitfantasist Will do!

Have you eliminated switch bounce as an explanation for what you describe?

You seem to be copy-pasting CircuitLab schematics as images into your questions. Instead, please use the CircuitLab editor via a button built into this site's Q&A editor toolbar. That way the schematic is editable - both for you and for those who want to use it to demonstrate some changes or problems in an answer.

@Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica Noted, will do from now on, thanks!

Simple tips

Really, the simplest tip is to briefly press the push button. Then you could hold the push-button for a longer time until the capacitor C1 has not yet managed to charge to its final voltage.

Another simple tip is to increase C1 capacitance. Then you could hold the push-button for a longer time until the capacitor C1 has not yet managed to charge to its final voltage. But then you may have to wait for C1 to charge.


Circuit operation
Whatever it is, it is still a good reason to look at a circuit operation when the push-button is pressed for a long time. Then the circuit drawn by @Simon Fitch is in effect.
Without hysteresis
Let's assume that C1 is discharged and you press (and hold) SW1. Then NOT1's output is HIGH and NOT2's output is LOW. R1 and R2 form a voltage divider with a "gain" of R2/(R1 + R2) = 0.5 that is "stretched" between the two opposite outputs (R1 is connected to Vcc and R2 to ground); so its output voltage is half of the supply voltage. As a result, the capacitor C1 tends to charge up to this voltage.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
When C1 voltage approaches this voltage, NOT1 and NOT2 begin changing their output voltages in the opposite direction (like in a bridge circuit). Now R1 is connected to ground and R2 to Vcc but the transfer ratio is the same - R1/(R1 + R2) = 0.5. So the divider output voltage is the same, i.e. the voltage across the capacitor has not changed.

simulate this circuit
Given the fact that this voltage is around the switching threshold of NOT1 and NOT2, they can draw significant current because both of their output stage transistors are conducting.
With hysteresis
If the NOT gates have Schmitt-trigger inputs (hysteresis), it can be expected that the circuit will switch at a relatively low (apparent) frequency because it will be a classical relaxation oscillator.
But there is a problem - as we have already seen, the capacitor C1 only charges to half the supply voltage... and will never reach the upper threshold of the Schmitt trigger...
How to make T flip-flop
(per OP's comment below)
An asynchronous T flip-flop can be made by a synchronous D flip-flop. So, let's first see what a D flip-flop is.
D flip-flop
Let's initially the push-button is off, so C = 0. Also assume Q = 0 and Q' = 1.

When the push-button is pressed (with a positive edge of the clock C), what is waiting at the input D (e.g., 1) appears and remains at the output Q, and its negation at the output Q'.

Similarly, if 0 is waiting at D...

... when SW is pressed, Q = 0 and Q' = 1...

... and it remains even if SW is released.

T flip-flop
So, if we connect Q' to D...

... the opposite (1) of the flip-flop's current state (0) will wait on the D input.

If we press SW, the current state (0) will change to the opposite state (1)...

... and its negation (0) will wait at D.

If we press SW again, the flip-flop will change its current state (1) to the opposite (0)...

... and will remain in the new state.


I ordered a few NOT gates with Schmitt-triggers, but your last sentence worries me now, because yeah, it makes sense that the cap would only charge up to the voltage divider. Hmm, so what is the solution? I am also totally open to other latch circuits, it doesn't have to be this one. I just need one that's reliable and has a very low quiescent current. I also tried a couple of transistor and MOSFET latches, but those (at least for me) are invariably too sensitive and leaky and end up either impossible to turn off or on.

@Victor Stanciu, Keep in mind that this is still a tinkering solution. It's better to use a standard T flip-flop. If you insist on doing it this way, connect the inverted output of a D flip-flop to its input and the push-button to the clock input.

The clock is the problem. The "device" I am designing is powered by a tiny CR435 battery, which only has a capacity of around 50mAh. I need something with a minuscule quiescent current, preferably zero (though I can settle for something in the microamps range). So I thought I might implement something that didn't need a clock at all.

Wait, or am I misunderstanding something?

@@Victor Stanciu, This arrangement (D flip-flop acting as a T flip-flop) is asynchronous. The D input
acts as an internal feedback input, and the clock has become an input of the new T flip-flop. Do you know it?

I don't, but thank you for pointing me in an actionable direction. I'm a beginner so I have no idea how flip flops work, but I can for sure research. Thanks!

Thank you for the flip flop demonstration, that is very useful! In the meanwhile I read a bit on flip flops. Since the switch is now connected to the clock, doesn't that mean that the state of the flip flop will be "random"? While the clock signal is on, the state flips as fast as the chip is able to, and since the switch is mechanical, the moment it disconnects might fall on the 0 or 1 states of the flip flop output. Should I add a Schmitt trigger after the switch, or what would be the best way to guarantee that a press (even a longer one) only generates one short pulse?

And I'll also have to debounce the switch I believe, right?

@Victor Stanciu, This D flip-flop responds to the clock input only at the time of its change from 0 to 1 (ie, on the positive edge). You should debounce the mechanical push-button because it will count down a few bounces.

Ahh, that's what Positive-Edge-Triggered means in datasheets, I understand now, that's really cool. Thanks a lot!

When the switch is closed, the inverters section of the circuit simplifies to this:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
I suspect R1 and R2 are averaging the signals at Y and Z, and after a while C1 charges up to that average, presenting about half the supply voltage at X.
Since the inverters do not have schmitt trigger inputs, this places G1 in its linear(ish) region, acting more like an amplifier than a logic gate, and maybe G2 also. Negative feedback around G1 via R1 will help G1 to settle at a DC operating point in that linear region. In this state a push-pull CMOS output pair would have plenty of shoot-through current, which could account for the 40mA you are seeing.
Also, since you have positive feedback via R2, I imagine there could easily be severe oscillation about that half-way point, which would also cause a lot of IC supply current.
I don't know why this happens only for the 74LVC variant, and not 74HC. I think one would have to study the differences at the transistor level, to conclude anything meaningful.
I feel that the solution might be to employ schmitt-trigger input gates, like the 74HC132, but while that would keep the gates out of a "half-way" state, you might accidentally be creating a relaxation oscillator instead.

Mosaic Industries, if they ever built and tested, the circuit, would see the same problems.  It's not dependant on the gate or inverter variant. It should always act that way. When the switch is released, after a long press, the latch should go to some stable state, either set or reset, probably the same state every time.

@stretch I am addressing the switch closed condition, after a long time. I didn't talk at all about what happens when the switch opens.

@SimonFitch I will play around with other ICs (including one with a Schmitt trigger) and report back, thanks!

The two chips are very different. Yes they are both inverters, but the LVC type is capable of significantly faster operation than the HC type. And, they both are used outside the recommended operating conditions, and not even a supply bypass capacitor is used. The LVC chip is just too fast to operate properly in place of HC chip in the same not very good environment. The HC may work adequately in same environment.
The LVC being faster means it needs a better environment to work properly. Fast transitions on the output require a large surge of energy so the supply bypass capacitor is a must so that chip supply voltage does not sag under high but short current draw due to supply wiring inductance.
But that's not really the only thing. The circuit violates the chip requirements for proper operation. The HC type chip needs inputs to transition at a rate of 500 to 1000 ns per volt to work properly. The LVC type needs faster 20ns per volt transitions to work properly. Also the input voltage should fulfill the maximum low voltage or minimum voltage so the voltage does not float slowly between the transition area for too long. Which the RC circuit will violate, as it slows down the signals.
When input voltage sits in the middle of the transition area, both the P and N FETs of input stage will conduct between VCC and GND, that's called shoot-through current. As there is feedback, the output may even oscillate at tens of MHz while it keeps the input right in the middle of transition region. A kind of relaxation oscillator. It will consume a lot current, both due to shoot-through, and with the tens of millions of times per second charging and discharging stray, parasitic and input capacitances.
What you need is something with Schmitt trigger input like HC14 instead of HC04.

You need to use Schmitt trigger input inverters. Do not use the chips you did. You are using them well outside their specifications, and causing their internal inverter stages to cross-conduct, "shorting" VCC and GND.
The problem with the schematic of this circuit is that the Schmitt trigger symbols have been "lost in translation". The original circuit diagram was labeled correctly. But the various internet content farms just mindlessly copy and "improve" that stuff. In the end it doesn't work.
Here is an example of how a Schmitt-trigger-input inverter should look on a schematic. Taken from TI's 74AHC14 datasheet:

That little symbol inside the triangle represents the hysteresis I/O curve of a Schmitt trigger. Once you lose that symbol, the schematic represents something else - something that will not work.
